# Deleting an Object Allocated Through Placement New?

Tags: c++, c++17, placement-new

I have the following code:

```
struct SomeStruct2 {
    // has 4 primitive types of variables
};

struct SomeStruct1 {
    // has 10 primitive types of variables
    std::deque<SomeStruct2> foo;
};

template <class Data>
class ResourcePool {
public:
    void recycle(Data* data_ptr) {
        // do some work
        data_ptr->~data_ptr();
    }
};
```

For some reasons, every few days (after running the application for like 8 hours a day), it would coredump:

```
(gdb) bt

#0  0x00007fa443e32387 in raise () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007fa443e33a78 in abort () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#2  0x00007fa443e74f67 in __libc_message () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#3  0x00007fa443e7d329 in _int_free () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#4  0x0000000000434528 in __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<MyClass::SomeStruct2>::deallocate (this=0x87a410, __p=0x86f260, __t=16) at /opt/rh/devtoolset-10/root/usr/include/c++/10/ext/new_allocator.h:133
#5  0x000000000043147e in deallocate (__n=16, __p=0x86f260, this=0x87a410) at /opt/rh/devtoolset-10/root/usr/include/c++/10/bits/allocator.h:187
#6  std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<MyClass::SomeStruct2> >::deallocate (__a=..., __p=0x86f260, __n=16) at /opt/rh/devtoolset-10/root/usr/include/c++/10/bits/alloc_traits.h:492
#7  0x000000000042e73a in std::_Deque_base<MyClass::SomeStruct2, std::allocator<MyClass::SomeStruct2> >::_M_deallocate_node (this=0x87a410, __p=0x86f260) at /opt/rh/devtoolset-10/root/usr/include/c++/10/bits/stl_deque.h:566
#8  0x000000000042b8ae in std::_Deque_base<MyClass::SomeStruct2, std::allocator<MyClass::SomeStruct2> >::_M_destroy_nodes (this=0x87a410, __nstart=0x86f988, __nfinish=0x86f990) at /opt/rh/devtoolset-10/root/usr/include/c++/10/bits/stl_deque.h:676
#9  0x00000000004263ad in std::_Deque_base<MyClass::SomeStruct2, std::allocator<MyClass::SomeStruct2> >::~_Deque_base (this=0x87a410, __in_chrg=<optimized out>) at /opt/rh/devtoolset-10/root/usr/include/c++/10/bits/stl_deque.h:598
#10 0x000000000042643f in std::deque<MyClass::SomeStruct2, std::allocator<MyClass::SomeStruct2> >::~deque (this=0x87a410, __in_chrg=<optimized out>) at /opt/rh/devtoolset-10/root/usr/include/c++/10/bits/stl_deque.h:1004
#11 0x00000000004270c2 in MyClass::SomeStruct1::~SomeStruct1 (this=0x87a388, __in_chrg=<optimized out>) at my.hpp:67
#12 0x0000000000427109 in ResourcePool<MyClass::SomeStruct1>::recycle (this=0x7ffc3a6f9480, pData=0x87a388) at ResourcePool.hpp:94
#13 0x0000000000422579 in MyClass::try_recycle (this=0x7ffc3a6f9270, data_ptr=0x87a388) at my.hpp:292
#14 0x0000000000421cf9 in MyClass::timer_expired_callback (local_timer_id=8845808, epochExpiration=1679894068466539651, opaqueData=0x7ffc3a6f9270) at my.hpp:453
```

I then ran gdb to go to frame 11 and `p *this`, the content doesn't look like corrupted.

Any idea why it caused coredump sometimes when I tried to delete an objected allocated through placement new?  The strange thing is that it died when it tried to deallocate the `std::deque` inside `SomeStruct1`.  `gdb` shows that the `std::deque` has no argument.

Comment: please post a [mcve]. The coredump is surely not from the code you included here

Comment: Things don't have to look corrupted just because they don't exist.

Comment: crash in this location probably means your program corrupted the heap and this is the point where some other unrelated heap operation detected that the heap was corrupted. Notice the function __libc_message suggesting a message was printed (and not seen by you). Running your program in `valgrind` will often find memory corruption quickly - note the program runs more slowly, as it is emulated.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number yes you are right.  I wish I could.  But it has some IP issue and so I can't post the minimal reproducible example.

Comment: You most likely try every few days to recycle what has been already recycled because of some defective corner case handling. That handling should be below #12 in your core dump.

Comment: You probably need to run an "address sanitizer" build, however this has quite a server performance impact so probably in a test environment only.

Comment: @ÖöTiib Actually my code has a timer that expires every ~8ms to do some cleanup.  But I also suspect that the object might have recycled.  Added more log to see whether it is the case.

Comment: @RichardCritten  That's actually a good call.  I remember that once the sanitizer detects an invalid access, it would abort?